# How do I get the values from input text fields from my custom form through the request: Django 3.0?

Tags: python, django, python-3.7, django-3.0

So, I've been trying hard, getting values from input fields in my custom form.

I have a url that corresponds to the form and that form redirects it to the same form again.

The view of the form url checks whether the request method is Post. If it is, then I declare a variable equal to `request.POST`, I then assigned those values to my model- item_description(). Here is the code of the `views.py`:

```
def addItem(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        data = request.POST
        print(data.__dict__)
        item_description(item_name=data.item_name, item_number=data.item_number, item_quantity=data.item_quantity)

    else:
        HttpResponse("Something went wrong!")

    return render(request, 'ims/addItemForm.html')
```

**HTML form:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>IMS| Add Item</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="{% url 'Item-addition' %}" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <input type="text" name="item_name" placeholder="Enter Item Name">
        <input type="text" name="item_number" placeholder="Enter Item Number">
        <input type="text" name="item_quantity" placeholder="Enter Item Quantity">
        <button type="submit" name="add" value="add">Add Item</button>
    </form>

    <a href="{% url 'Items-list' %}">See items</a>

</body>
</html>
```

**urls.py:**

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('add_item', views.addItem, name='Item-addition'),
    path('items', views.itemsList, name='Items-list'),
]
```

**models.py:**

```
from django.db import models

class item_description(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item_quantity = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name
```

Also, I printed out the request which is a dictionary, but it was not having any of the values. Here is the printed request dictionary: `{'_encoding': 'utf-8', '_mutable': False}`.

Here is the error which I am getting:

> File "/home/zaid/inventoryManagement/venv/src/ims/views.py", line 13, in addItem
>       item_description(item_name=data.item_name, item_number=data.item_number, item_quantity=data.item_quantity)
>   AttributeError: 'QueryDict' object has no attribute 'item_name'

Please help me getting values from the input fields.

Comment: Instead of `data.item_name`, do `data['item_name']` or `data.get('item_name')`.

Comment: Please use [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) rather than manually rendering the form and handling the POST data on your own. `ModelForm` can construct your HTML form, and it comes with input validation.

Comment: Thanks,  no error now but my admin page does not show up that item that i added. Why is that? Did the item did not get added to the model? Also, the dictionary returns the same {'_encoding': 'utf-8', '_mutable': False} indicating that the values were not added to the dictionary of the request, right?

Comment: I repeat: change your code to use [ModelForm](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/). Unless you have excellent reasons for not using `ModelForm`, people will be reluctant to help you if you show little interest in doing things properly. Have you changed your code to use `ModelForm`?

Comment: Model forms actually confuses me,  i am not able to understand it. But still i'll try changing it

Comment: Then take the time to learn it before continuing. It's an important part of Django. You must understand how to use it.

Comment: Okay, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistakes:

```
item_description(item_name=data.item_name, item_number=data.item_number, item_quantity=data.item_quantity)
```

- `data` is a [`QueryDict`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects), so you must access the data in it using `data['item_name']` or `data.get('item_name')` as you would for a regular `dict`.
- `item_description(...)` doesn't actually do anything. It does not save anything to the database. To save to the database, you must use [`item_description.objects.create(...)`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#create).

Other problems with your code:

- you render the form fields on your own
- you extract the POST data on your own
- you attempt to save to the database on your own
- you are missing input validation (what if some required values are missing? e.g. what if `item_name` is not submitted?)
- you did not provide a suitable error message as feedback to the user if he/she enters inappropriate values (e.g. a string of length 201).

Django's [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/) is able to handle all of these issues, so please use `ModelForm` instead.

If `models.py` is this:

```
from django.db import models

class ItemDescription(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item_number = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    item_quantity = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name
```

Then, create a `ModelForm` in `forms.py`:

```
from django import forms
from .models import ItemDescription

class ItemDescriptioneForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ItemDescription
        fields = ['item_name', 'item_number', 'item_quantity']
```

In your `views.py`, use the `ModelForm` you just created:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import ItemDescriptionForm

def addItem(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ItemDescriptionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('Items-list')
    else:
        form = ItemDescriptionForm()

    return render(request, 'ims/addItemForm.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

Show the form in your template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add Item</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```